# RadGrid inside RadWindow having issues in grid sorting

Tags: asp.net, telerik

In my aspx page I have a RadPageView which contains RadWindow and the RadGrid is inside the RadWindow. (ie. RadMultiPage -> RadPageView -> RadWindow -> RadGrid).

```
  <telerik:RadWindow EnableShadow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" runat="server"
                                        ReloadOnShow="true" Title="Standard Text: Add Observation." OpenerElementID="lnkObservationsText"
                                        Behaviors="None" VisibleStatusbar="false" EnableViewState="true" ID="rdWndObservationText"
                                        Skin="Web20" Modal="true" Width="600">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <div class="RadModalMainDiv">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Help text to go here....</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="divStandardTextButtonList">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnObservationsTextSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CssClass="btnStandardText"
                                                        OnClientClick="return ObservationStandardText_Confirm()" />
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnObservationsTextCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btnStandardText" />
                                                </div>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="radGdObservationsText" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" PageSize="10" Width="100%">
                                                            <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" Name="ParentGrid">
                                                                <Columns>
                                                                    <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn">
                                                                    </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                                                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="description" HeaderText="Observation Description"
                                                                        Visible="true">
                                                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </MasterTableView>
                                                            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                                                            <ClientSettings>
                                                                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                                                                <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="SetObservationStandardText" />
                                                            </ClientSettings>
                                                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                                                    </div>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                            </div>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </telerik:RadWindow>
```

When I try to sort the grid clicking on the header, the page refreshes and the RadWindow disappears. Sorting happens coz when i reopens the RadGrid the rows appea sorted. I need the RadGrid to be sroted and remain in the same state.
Thanks for all helps in prior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reopen the RadWindow manually in order for this to work. I can suggest that you try an easier approach. Remove the OpenerElementID and modify the button that open the RadWindow and the other one that closes it as shown below:

Click handler for the button that open/close the window:

```
 void lnkObservationsText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     rdWndObservationText.VisibleOnPageLoad = !rdWndObservationText.VisibleOnPageLoad;
 }
```

Click handler code for the close button that resides in the RadWindow itself

```
void btnObservationsTextCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rdWndObservationText.VisibleOnPageLoad = false;
}
```

In this case you won't need to use ReloadOnShow.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)